# Build is started and terminated immediately using devenv /deploy

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, command-line, devenv

I am using devenv command line switches to build and deploy a project. Build is getting started and the project is never deployed. I am using the following line of code

`devenv "%pathtosolution%" /deploy Debug /project "%relativepathtoprojectfile%" /projectconfig "Debug|x64"`

This is what I am seeing after that

`1>------ Build started: Project: %projectname%, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE>`

Am I missing any switch/argument?

Answer (score 0):

Try `%pathtosolution%` in place of `%pathtosolution` and `%relativepathtoprojectfile%` in place of `%relativepathtoprojectfile`

in Winbatch, variables are accessed using `%var%`, not `%var`

Comment: sorry that was a type. I actually used `%pathtosolution%` not `%pathtosoltion`. Updating the original question